# how to add vallue using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, trim

```
$("#totalinvoicevalue").text($.trim($('#total_product_gst').html()) + totalcharge.toFixed(2));

$.trim($('#total_product_gst').html()) = 1050.00  
totalchage = 100
```

I get result 1050.00100
I expect 1150.00
please help how to deal with it in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse your string to a float :

```
let totalProductGst = parseFloat($.trim($('#total_product_gst').html()));
let totalCharge = parseFloat(totalcharge.toFixed(2));
$("#totalinvoicevalue").text( totalProductGst + totalCharge );
```